Are TimeMachine backup files accessible outside of Mac OS?
If I plug an external hard drive containing time machine backups on it into a Windows or Linux computer, will I be able to enter the password to decrypt and access the files, or will I be unable to access the data without acquiring another Mac?

Recent versions of the macOS format Time Machine volumes as APFS. So your non-Mac computer would have to be able to read that format. I believe that's possible with third-party software, but maybe not if the volume is encrypted.
